# Php preg_match multiple occurrences, return unique array

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to be able to extract certain parts of the string and return unique array. Here is my string:

```
$string = "
  <div> some text goes here... **css/method|1|2**</div>
  <div>**php/method|3|4**</div>
  <div>**html|method|6|9** and more text here</div>
  <div>**html/method|2|5**</div>
";
```

using `preg_match_all()`

```
$pattern = "/**(.*?)**/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
```

I can extract all the parts from the string, but I need to go step further, and only return the following:

css, php and html.

the final array should look like this:

```
$result = array("css", "php", "html");
```

So basically, I need to eliminate duplicate values in this case "html", as well as extract each value before backslash or pipe. I don't care about method parts as well as what goes after.

Comment: `*` has special meaning in regular expressions, you need to escape them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution using `preg_match_all` and `array_unique` functions:

```
preg_match_all("~\*\*([^/|*]+)(?=[/|])~", $string, $matches);
$result = array_unique($matches[1]);
print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => css
    [1] => php
    [2] => html
)
```

`(?=[/|])` - positive lookahead assertion which matches word that is followed by one of the characters `/|`

---

***Update***: to ignore tags from match update regex pattern with the following `~\*\*([^/|*<>]+)(?=[/|])~`

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I delete my post, I don't understand the (?=[/|]) in you post.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, Thanks this works great, but for some reason if I have additional html or text within code it does not work. for example "Lorem ipsum **css/method|1|2** dolores..."

Comment: @KrisRoofe, added some explanation

Comment: @Alko, but how about preceding `**` characters from your initial condition? What should be the delimiter in your new multiline text?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes, I did that, but I'm not able to insert asterisk here for some reason. So everything works great, but if I have some html code within string, then only the first match is found `<div>**css/method|1|2**</div><div>**php/method|1|2**</div>`

Comment: @Alko, please, update(edit) your question with a new input string

Comment: @Alko, see my **Update** notation